# Sliding in Bootstrap 3 Carousel doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to work on an images carousel, the issue is that there is no smooth sliding between the carousel items, so it switch from one item to another without a transition animation.

Please check the live demo [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/slider/index.html)

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
});
```

JS files:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Culprit is jQuery you are using. use the latest from 1.10.x or 2.x.x :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have just included the custom bootstrap js file (**Carousel functionality** js)... You must download the **Transitions** js also to get the sliding effect .. Refer bootstrap customize page and download the **Carousel functionality** and **Transitions** .. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You are using 1.9.1 js file

and bootstrap is using 1.11.1

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

replace 1.9.1 js with 1.11.1 js